# ESS - stop move point to end when the buffer is updated

Tags: ess

Whenever the R process redirect new output to the process buffer, Emacs move the point to the end of the buffer. This is annoy when user want to check previous commands or output that are outside of the window. How to stop Emacs doing this? Could the solution applied to all the shell process, like python, shell etc?

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is controlled by `comint-scroll-to-bottom-on-output`. It's `nil` by default. You probably configured it to a different value accidentally.

Comment: thanks. should have be more conscious when cover someone's config. :d